# Helm Cannot Read Chart.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, apache-nifi, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy Apache Nifi on Kubernetes using helm but when I execute this command:

**helm install --name test-nifi --namespace nifi ./apache-nifi-helm**

I immediately get an error saying:

**Error: cannot read Chart.Yaml in directory "/home/mydir/test/apache-nifi"**

And I have checked the directory and it certainly contains the Chart.Yaml file. I have cloned it from a GitHub Repo.

Am I making a mistake somewhere? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version helm you use?
Сan you provide a link to the repository?

Comment: Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.9.1",

Comment: Here's the repo: https://github.com/markap14/apache-nifi-helm

Answer (score 0):

You can

**Clone repo:**

`$ git clone git@github.com:markap14/apache-nifi-helm.git`

**Run helm:**

`$ helm install --name test-nifi --namespace ${YOU_NAMESPACE} ./apache-nifi-helm/charts/zookeeper-0.4.2.tgz  --tiller-namespace ${YOU_NAMESPACE}`

Answer (score 0):

I've also been getting the

```
 "cannot read Chart.Yaml in directory XYZ" error
```

from helm install in spite of the presence of a Chart.yaml file in the directory.

In the end it was other configuration problems (I had template in the 'charts' folder).

Hooray for the friendly error message!